# Dynamic DLL sometimes cause exception

Tags: c#, wpf, exception, dynamic, dll

I'm using dynamic dll's with my wpf application, I can load a dll just fine, I can set events or enter to a simple function and return from it, I just got one function that sometimes throw me: 
"An unexpected exception occurred while binding a dynamic operation" exception.

It's not happening all the time, usually just after switching between dll's. 
The only workaround I found was to create a new class library and then it works fine, until next time...

Loading the dll:

```
        Assembly asm = Assembly.LoadFile( unitDllPath );
        Type typ = asm.GetType( Globals.UnitUnderTestComboBox + ".Class1", true, true );             
        unitDll = Activator.CreateInstance( typ );
```

Setting event and entering the dll to retrieve value:

```
  unitDll.TerminateDll += new EventHandler( eventTerminateDll );

  unitSerial = unitDll.GetSerialSCPICommand();
```

The "problematic" function

```
 calibrationResult = unitDll.Execute( ref Globals.MessageInput, ref Globals.ImageInput, mbUnitSession, mbDeviceSession, Globals.ImagesDirectory, deviceDllPath, Globals.TestFilePath, Globals.Name, Globals.Address, Globals.Family, Globals.SelectedCalibrationSetup, Globals.StartSetupIndex, Globals.EndSetupIndex, Globals.PrintInformationToFile, Globals.SelectedChannel );
```

Anyone knows what can I do to prevent this exception?

Thanks!

Edit:

Complete exception details:
   at System.Environment.GetStackTrace(Exception e, Boolean needFileInfo)
   at System.Environment.get_StackTrace()
   at AutoCalibration.Calibration.CalibrationMethod() in D:\Dov\Applications\AutoCalibration\AutoCalibration final 20.01.16\AutoCalibration\AutoCalibration\Calibration.cs:line 145
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()

Comment: I suspect there are more details within the exception, e.g. in the InnerException. Please include a *complete* stack trace within your question.

Comment: Hope I understand you correctly, I edited my question and added a link for the exception details.

Comment: Please edit the exception stack trace into the question as *text* rather than as a screenshot which doesn't even capture the InnerException.

Comment: I'm not sure I've done what you asked me to, if I'm wrong please explain what I'm doing wrong.

About InnerException:
If I'm debugging and pressing on "Open exception helper" and then pressing "copy exception detail to the clipboard" all I see is what I posted in the screenshot, there is no indication to InnerException.

Comment: No, it's not... why are you calling `GetStackTrace`? The screenshot you provided before was providing the text that I wanted to be *as text* in the question, and the bottom line was "InnerException" suggesting that if you'd scrolled down further you'd have got the useful bit...

Comment: InnerException is Null.
And I can't paste as text because the site thinks its code, and not allow it.

Comment: So quote it as code... that way it'll maintain the formatting. You definitely *can* post stack traces in SO questions.